# cleartimeout Animation inside Settimeout in reactjs from array of locations when request for another animation during that period

Tags: reactjs, animation, settimeout, setstate, cleartimeout

I would like to clear the timeout issue when user click for another request while one animation is ongoing. I want to mention that this will occur on the same component map. I am new in ReactJS and would expect an answer. Thanks in advance.

**My setState code looks like this...**

```
result.map((mark, index)=>{
          setTimeout(()=>{
            this.setState({
              markers: [mark]  // assume result = [[10,12], [12,14]...]
            })
          }, index * 5);
        });
```